# Multiple list comprehensions from a single CSV file source

Tags: python, pandas, csv, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use list comprehensions to get specific columns from a CSV file source.

Here's some code that simulates the CSV file data that I see:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Setup of simulated data
seconds = [1,2,3]
values = [0.5,0.4,0.3]
non_relevant_data = [8,6,7]
nanos = [5757,6767,7777]
dataset=list(zip(seconds,values,non_relevant_data,nanos))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False,header=False,name=None)
table=pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=None).itertuples(index=False,name=None)
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
# Getting each column in the table using list comprehensions
secs = np.array([row[0] for row in table])
vals = np.array([row[1] for row in table])
nano = np.array([row[3] for row in table])

print secs
print vals
print nano
```

Here's the result:

```
[1 2 3]
[]
[]
```

If I comment out the secs list comprehension object, and leave the vals and nano variables uncommented, this is the result:

```
[0.5 0.4 0.3]
[]
```

If I use a for loop and pre-define the secs, vals, and nano arrays, I can get the code to work, but that's not very elegant.

I also tried this without using numpy, but it yielded the same result.

I'm very confused why the list comprehensions don't work in this configuration.

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work, or recommend something else to try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
table=pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

secs = np.array([row[0] for row in table.itertuples(index=False,name=None)])
vals = np.array([row[1] for row in table.itertuples(index=False,name=None)])
nano = np.array([row[3] for row in table.itertuples(index=False,name=None)])
```

The reason why your version isn't working is because `itertuples` creates a zip object (an iterator of named tuples representing the rows) which can be iterated once. So you have to create a new one for each of the list comprehensions `secs`, `vals`, `nano`.